# GWT not properly rendering on Chrome

Tags: gwt, google-chrome

I've a really really weird bug in production.
For some customers and some setups (this can happen on a Linux and a Windows box), our GWT application doesn't render in full (there are a widgets that are missing). The weird thing is that if we ask our customers to start the JavaScript debugger (CTRL-SHIFT-J on Windows), the content displays. Viewing using another browser (like FF) works.

We've been banging our heads bloody a few days now... any ideas?

Comment: Any consistency in the Chrome versions where this happens?

Comment: nope. we've tried the same versions as our customers, but works on our end, which makes it even more frustrating.

Comment: The possible problem may be concerned with the layout broken by CSS styling or event loop or else. As a dirty quick fix you can try to simulate resizing panels that implements RequiresResize. RootLayoutPanel.get().onResize(); or possibly you can try to simulate window resize. Window.resizeTo(Window.getClientWidth(), Window.getClientHeight()); I'm not shure. you've provided not enough information about your problem.

Comment: Just asked one of our customer (who's experiencing this problem) to resize the browser window...no difference.

Comment: Some more info: So when the page first loads, it does a ajax request back to the server to get the current user. Once the current user is in the browser, there are a couple of tabs. Click a tabe "past logs" for example, spawns another ajax requests that fetches a bunch of log objects. During the fetching process a spinner wait wheel is displayed as the tab content. Once the log entries are returned the wait wheel disappears, and the log entries should display (but doesnt). All that remains is an tab with empty content

Comment: SOLVED.

it appears the customers were using a adblocker....grrr

Comment: @user1082357: If it solved your problem, please post it as the answer and mark as it so (yes, you can accept your own answer on your own question - you might even get a badge if enough people vote it up). This way, more people could easily benefit from your finding :)

Comment: ...i did try that...stack overflow popup up a message saying i cant answer my own question within 8h

Comment: Same problem here on an older Safari version, no adblocker installed. Widget is in DOM, but browser does not resize container div to show it. Setting DIV height manually shows the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with the height of the component containing your logs objects. Did you try to set a fixed height in pixel? I assume once you open the debugger window, Chrome is forced to render the page again and adjusts the height of the container, so your elements become visible.